# How to fix Error: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element. error?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have compiled my project using Webpack. However, when I launch my html, only my background color displays but nothing else and I get the following error in the console:

```
Error: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.
```

This is my HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="public/bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssWEB.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And my JS:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Element, scroller} from 'react-scroll';


const Component = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function() {
        scroller.scrollTo('myScroller', {
            duration: 1500,
            delay: 500,
            smooth: true
        });
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
              <link rel="stylesheet/less" href="style.less" type="text/css" />
              <script src="http://lesscss.googlecode.com/files/less-1.0.21.min.js"></script>
              <link type="text/javascript" href="jscode.js"></link>


              <header>
                My Page
              </header>

              <body ng-app="App">
                <div class="cube" change-background colorcode="#f45642" ref={(el) => { this.messagesEnd = el; }}>
                  <div class="front"><span>Resume</span></div>
                  <div class="back"></div>
                  <div class="top"></div>
                  <div class="bottom"></div>
                  <div class="left"></div>
                  <div class="right"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="wrap2">
                  <div class="cube" change-background>
                    <div class="front" colorcode="#f45642"><span>Work</span></div>
                    <div class="back"></div>
                    <div class="top"></div>
                    <div class="bottom"></div>
                    <div class="left"></div>
                    <div class="right"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="wrap3">
                  <div class="cube" change-background>
                    <div class="front" colorcode="#f45642"><span>Contact</span></div>
                    <div class="back"></div>
                    <div class="top"></div>
                    <div class="bottom"></div>
                    <div class="left"></div>
                    <div class="right"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </body>

              <Element name="link1">
                <div class="bg2" id="linkhere"></div>
              </Element>

              <div class="slide1">
              </div>

              <div class="slidechild1">
              <div class="centerbox">
              <div class="center">
                <ul>
                  <li ng-click="clicked2()" id="B1">aa</li>
                  <li id="B2">cc.i</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>

        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Component />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

What is wrong with my code that is raising this error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because `document.getElementById("root")` would return a DOM element after the document has loaded, this suggests that your script runs before the DOM element has been created.

Looking at your HTML confirms this. You load `bundle.js` in the head, but at that point the document body has not loaded.

To solve this issue, you can move your script tag below the `div` element to ensure the element has been created by the time the script runs.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssWEB.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="public/bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: awesome explanation +1 for that :)

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue, and for my situation the following resolved the issue:

I used jQuery ready function to load the render() function. Also I put the bundle.js script at the end of the body and specified it as defer.

```
<body>
    <div id="main">{{{markup}}}</div>

    <script src="/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/tether/dist/js/tether.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="../../static/bundle-main.js" defer></script>
  </body>
```

The following is my render function:

```
$(function () {
    render(<App />, document.getElementById('main'));
});
```

I am using handlebars here to inject the result of React from server (FYI has nothing to do with the issue).

Why this happens? Because the bundle script is loaded before the DOM renders completely so the script is not able to find the element, say `<div id='main'></div>`. Specifying defer ensures that the script is rendered after the page is rendered. 
Making the render function enclosed inside jQuery ready function ensures that render function is executed on DOM ready.

Hope this answer resolves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try document.querySelector instead of document.getElementById